# Textfield not working once clicked on in the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the Google Maps SDK and currently I have a map that will route the user from wherever they are to a specific location. I would like for the user to be able to input where they want to go, rather than always being routed to the same location. I added a text field to the GUI and whenever I run the app in the simulator and click the textfield, no keyboard comes up and it acts as though I did not tap on it.

Here is how I have set up my project:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate
{

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    var keyy = "myKeyIsHere"
    var didFindMyLocation = false
    var count: Int = 0
    var button = UIButton()
    var latitude = UITextField()
    var longitude = UITextField()
    var path = GMSMutablePath()

super.viewDidLoad()
        let blah = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 39.8282, longitude: -98.5795, zoom: 25.0)
        mapView.camera = blah
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

        currLocation = mapView.myLocation?.coordinate

        button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 135, y: 40, width: 100, height: 40)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        button.setTitle("Route", for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        latitude = UITextField()
        latitude.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 90, width: 175, height: 35)
        latitude.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        latitude.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        latitude.layer.borderWidth = 1
        latitude.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        latitude.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        latitude.text = " Enter Latitude"
        latitude.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
        self.latitude.delegate = self

        longitude = UITextField()
        longitude.frame = CGRect(x: 195, y: 90, width: 175, height: 35)
        longitude.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        longitude.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        longitude.layer.borderWidth = 1
        longitude.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        longitude.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        longitude.text = " Enter Longitude"
        longitude.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
        self.longitude.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(latitude)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        self.view.addSubview(longitude)
    }
```

There is more but this all I feel is relevant for the problem. Ive actually added two text fields here, and neither work! Please help!

Comment: kind a interesting problem. Are you testing it in your simulator?

Comment: ive tried using the simulator, and also using my own phone!

Comment: Since i am creating all of my GUI elements in the view controller, should i just delete the main.storyboard entirely?

Comment: Try. Shift+option+command+k to clean your project and rebuild.see that works..

Comment: Is your TexField  control state enabled? on Attributes inspector

Comment: Try yourTextFieldName.isEnabled = true

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your problem and buttonPressed code?

Comment: did you implement my answer into your viewDidLoad ?

Comment: i have no problem running your code.just tested in swift 3.. try override func viewDidLoad() { } rather super.viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: Nope. Don't delete your storyboard. I believe it's not related to your storyboard. Have your wrote textfield delegate methods in your code? Then check textFieldShouldBeging function, if your wrote anything like resigning that textfield keyboards. Other then, I don't see any reason of not showing the keyboard even you wrote your textfield declaration by coding.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "try override func viewDidLoad rather than super.viewDidLoad"? I currently have a call to super.viewDidLoad() from within my override func viewDidLoad method.

Comment: check my update.....

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the `Control State of your textField` as below from storyboard or programatically.

[image]

```
 latitude.isEnabled = true
 longitude.isEnabled = true
```

**Updated**:

**Note:** Move all your code inside `viewDidLoad?` like below

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 }
```

Try one of the below method to enable textField.When textField begin editing...

```
  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  print("textFieldShouldBeginEditing:")
  return true
  }

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
  print("textFieldDidBeginEditing:")
  }
```

Comment: I have actually made just one button and it is called "time". I have added that line and it still doesnt work! Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to type in the textfield using your macs keyboard. If you want the keyboard to show up then press cmd + K in simulator to toggle software keyboard.

The keyboard will show up on device.

Comment: but it doesnt show up on the device or the simulator (even after toggling keyboard)

Comment: Since i am creating all of my GUI elements in the view controller, should i just delete the main.storyboard entirely?

Comment: I dont think deleting the storyboard is the problem. Are you able to see text when you 

textField.text = "demo"

Answer (score 0):

Have your wrote textfield delegate methods in your code? Then check textFieldShouldBeging function, if your wrote code to resigning that textfield keyboard. Other then, I don't see any reason of not showing the keyboard even you wrote your textfield declaration by coding.

As you wrote all of your elements programmatically in your class, check if any of the element override your textfield. That's why even you think you are clicking on the textfield, you are actually clicking something else.

Comment: no i have not written any delegate methods! What are they?

Comment: Please copy paste your full view did method and any related method which is responsible for UI design here.

Answer (score 0):

Please move all of your buttons and textfields declaration from 'viewDidLoad' method to 'viewDidLayoutSubviews' method. If you are using auto layouts, then writing the buttons and textfield declaration in view did load method can cause issues.